# How to iterate through dataset comparing rows next to one another and output the relationship for results in new columns?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data set which lists a range of teams (e.g. "A", "B") and the id of the users in each team.

Example data set below (first 2 columns).Actual data runs in to the 500k plus, so I have been trying to implement a loop in R, without success.

[example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkk0X.png)

1. I want to be able assess each row against the next,

   i.e. if row 1 = team A & row 2 = team A, "pass",

   if row 1 = team A & row 2 = team B, "fail"

   if row 1 = team B & row 2 = team B, "pass"

   if row 1 = team B & row 2 = team A, "fail",

   with each iteration comparing the next set of rows (e.g. 1 compared to 2, then 2 to 3, and so on).

   The output for each being in a new column, detailing the outcome i.e pass/fail.
2. If the outcome is "pass", I would like 2 new columns the first having the user id in the first  row and the second the user in the row to which it was compared - like an edge list -e.g. in the desired output format below, row 1 and 2 are compared, each having team, and "Pass", therefore  user 1 is inserted into user_id_out, and user 2 into the user_id_in column.

If the outcome was fail, the content for user_id_out (and in), will be NA.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo9Ke.png)

Any help on how to do this will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using dplyr functions.

```r
library(dplyr)

# The data
data <- data.frame(
  team = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7)
)

data %>%
  mutate(
    outcome = case_when(
      team == lead(team) ~ 'pass',
      TRUE ~ 'fail'
    ),
    user_id_out = ifelse(outcome == 'pass', user_id, NA),
    user_id_in = ifelse(outcome == 'pass', lead(user_id), NA)
  )
#>    team user_id outcome user_id_out user_id_in
#> 1     A       1    pass           1          2
#> 2     A       2    pass           2          3
#> 3     A       3    pass           3          4
#> 4     A       4    fail          NA         NA
#> 5     B       5    pass           5          6
#> 6     B       6    pass           6          7
#> 7     B       7    fail          NA         NA
#> 8     A       1    fail          NA         NA
#> 9     B       5    fail          NA         NA
#> 10    A       3    pass           3          4
#> 11    A       4    fail          NA         NA
#> 12    B       6    pass           6          7
#> 13    B       7    fail          NA         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>